# Excel vba overflow error when evaluating date formatted cell which contains invalid data

Tags: excel, vba, date, overflow

I was entering data and I mistakenly entered my "Purchase Order Number" in the "Purchase Order Date" cell.

This resulted in an overflow error on the following line.

```
If Target.Column > 1 And Target <> "" Then
```

Target.Column evaluated to 2 as expected so I'm pretty sure it was failing on Target <> "" .

The target cell was set to date format and I typed "4502554236" in it (which doesn't evaluate to a correct date). Now looking on the sheet I see the cell is filled with ########### .

I was making sure the cell was not empty but I suppose I need to also check if the data in the cell isn't an error ?

What is the proper way to do that ?

thanks

Comment: There's more going on here than your `If` statement based on your comments on the answer by @GarysStudent. When I test this, I don't get an overflow until your *next* line of code.  Please post all of your code so we have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to test for errors in cells, you can use the `IsError()` function.  In your case, this isn't the problem and isn't what is causing the overflow on the following line. Having a value that can't be represented as a date in a cell is *not an error* (it is just invalid for that cell format) - Excel just displays it as a string of '#' instead. You can verify this by inserting this line, which will report "False":

```
Debug.Print IsError(Target)
```

The problem is that you rely on `Target` being a `Date`, so *that* is what you need to test for. Conveniently, there is an `IsDate` function you can test with. Try replacing your `If` statement with this:

```
`If Target.Column > 1 And IsDate(Target) Then`
```

This code afterwards also has a couple issues (from the comments):

```
If Target > "1899-12-30" And Target < "1900-02-01" Then _ 
   Target = CDate(Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & _
   Format(Day(Target + 1), "00"))
```

First, you are mixing `String` and `Date` types in your comparison, which can be a recipe for disaster because you are actually doing string comparisons as opposed to date comparisons. This is completely dependant on the format of the date.  Consider this line of code:

```
Debug.Print DateSerial(2000, 1, 1) > "1899-12-30"
```

It evaluates to False with my regional settings because it is basically testing this...

```
Debug.Print "1/1/2000" > "1899-12-30"
```

...and '/' happens to be "less than" '8'.

Note that since 1899-12-30 is the epoch date for VBA, you can replace this with a simple `> 0`. It is much safer, easier, and more readable to use `DateSerial` to build a date to test against. Note that you can also simplify your building of the formatted date string with a single call to `Format`:

```
Format$(Date + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

However, if you already have that in the cell format (evidenced by your string comparisons working), you can just let Excel do the formatting for you and set the date to the cell directly.  Combine all of that, and you get something like this:

```
If Target.Column > 1 And IsDate(Target) Then
    If Target > 0 And Target < DateSerial(1900, 2, 1) Then
        Target = Date + 1
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you that was very informative !

However at


     If Target.Column > 1 And Target <> "" Then


I don't understand why you say that I "rely on Target being a Date" ?

This evaluate changes for many cells (it is the first line in my Worksheet_Change). I I just want to make sure this is a cell from the first column and not empty. It only fails when a date cell has an invalid date in it.

Comment: You are right, date cells with invalid data are not errors. I put bad data in the cell and ...

    debug.Print iserror(activesheet.range("B7"))
    False

My code that is evaluating near epoch is to allow the user to just type the a two digit number (which then gets transformed into a date, so 21 becomes 1900-01-21, then I extract day() and replace with current month and year. If the date is later than 1900-02-01 then I leave it alone).  I'll try to make the code more readable with what you just taught me. thanks again

Comment: @Shodan - It was based on the test you do later for a Date.  If you only need to test for empty cells, use `IsEmpty` for that.  However, you should also check to see if a value is a Date before treating it like one.

Comment: OK, I understand !  I'll use that IsEmpty, it is more readable than ' <> "" '

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `Target` is only a **single cell** then you can always check with:

```
..........If Target.Text <> "" ...................
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix the overflow error at this line.

However it does not catch the error and goes on to fail on a subsequent line.

If Target > "1899-12-30" And Target < "1900-02-01" Then _
                Target = CDate(Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Format(Day(Target + 1), "00"))

I will try rejecting invalid dates with the Data validation excel feature described at http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/reject-invalid-dates.html .

Comment: Wouldn't that be a type mismatch instead of an overflow?

Comment: No, it says exactly,  Run-time error '6': 
Overflow

Comment: I just tried, Target.Text <> "#########################################" and that works for errors.